# How to extract match in a proper way using grep or another command?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have been looking into related questions on SO for days but I couldn't find an answer for my use-case. I want to `grep` a word after matching but without some special characters such as `quotes`, `comma`, `dash`. I have following line in my file.

```
...
"versionName": "1.1.5000-internal",
...
```

I want to extract the version itself without anything even `-internal` suffix, though but I am failed. Desired output would be as follows:

```
1.1.5000
```

What I've tried so far:

**1. I tried below to extract version name without surrounding quotes but it failed.**

```
grep -oP '(?<="versionName": )[^"]+(?=")' file.json
```

**2. This one gives the match with all specials.**

```
grep -oP '(?<="versionName": ).*' file.json | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

**3. This one works the same as the second one.**

```
grep '"versionName": ' file.json | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

I know there should be shorter and simpler approach but I am too bad at such stuff. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.versionName|sub("-.*";"")' file.json
```

Output:

```
1.1.5000
```

Comment: I know. Its syntax is Greek to me so usually I just stick to the good ol' tools.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `jq` (as you're clearly dealing with a JSON file)?

You can do:

```
jq -r .versionName file.json
```

Comment: Double quotes are part of the construct of an object in JSON and do no need removal if you use `jq`.

Comment: `jq -r .versionName file.json` if you don't want the quotes.

Comment: @blhsing: I've corrected my answer according to your remark.

Comment: You should show how to remove the `-internal` bit in jq, though even without that this is the most sensible answer.

Comment: @Shawn: how do you mean? (Feel free to update my answer accordlingly)

Comment: Thanks! This literally works but has a lack of some logic. For instance, I mentioned that I want to get rid of special chars. However, this is a good answer letting me switch to jq instead! Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
grep -oP '"versionName":\s*"\K[0-9.]+(?=[^"]*")' file.json
# Or, if there is no need to check for the trailing "
grep -oP '"versionName":\s*"\K[0-9.]+' file.json
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/UhTXbT).

*Details*:

- `"versionName":` - a literal, fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `[0-9.]+` - one or more digits/dots
- `(?=[^"]*")` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char.

If you need the first occurrence only, add `| head -1` after the `grep` command.

Comment: FYI, see a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yOCQha/1).

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep -oP and match the opening double quote. Then use `\K` to forget what is matched until now  and then match the version number.

```
"versionName": "\K\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=[^"]*")
```

**Explanation**

- `"versionName": "` Match literally, including the opening `"`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits with optional parts starting with a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?=[^"]*")` Assert a `"` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJDJDJ/1) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBBNz9AQV2pLLWoODM/zy8xN1XJSkEpxjsmRVvD3ipGD0hramnY20bHKcVqKWmqK9jY2GCqN9Qz1DM1MDDQzcwrSS3KS8xR0lH//x8A)

For example

```
grep -oP '"versionName": "\K\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=[^"]*")' file.json
```

Output

```
1.1.5000
```

---

Or using `sed` matching the whole line and capture the version number in group 1 and use it `\1` in the replacement.

```
sed -E 's/.*"versionName": "([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)[^"]*".*/\1/gm;t;d' file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can correct your first attempt by including the first double quote in the lookbehind and matching all subsequent characters that are neither double quotes nor dashes:

```
grep -oP '(?<="versionName": ")[^"-]+' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

A way with `awk` could be:

```
echo '"versionName": "1.1.5000-internal"' | awk -F'"|-' '{print $4}'
1.1.5000
```

Setting FS as `"|-` for this string and printing its corresponding field, `$4` in this case.

Or if you want to check previously:

```
echo '"versionName": "1.1.5000-internal"' | awk -F'"|-' '$2=="versionName"{print $4}'
1.1.5000
```